# Android Sqlite update between

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update my table data base on _id between range like 120 to 150. How can I update data using update or how can I do it  ?

Comment: [take a look](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_between.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following code :-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field1","Bob"); //These Fields should be your String values of actual column names
cv.put("Field2","19");
cv.put("Field2","Male");
myDB.update(TableName, cv, "_id>=120 and _id<=150", null);
```